# pyreverse classes.png only shows imports, not attributes

Tags: python, pyreverse

Hey I was trying to create a class diagram from pyreverse but it doesn't really show what I need.

I typed `pyreverse -o png -p folder .`

This is what I expected

[image]

This is what my packages.png looks like:

[image]

This is what the entire classes.png looks like:

[image]

I expected an output like the classes.png with the richness of the packages.png. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to declare something special in my Python code so that the classes and methods and ... are displayed in the packages.png? The only entry in the packages.png isn't even from my code, it's someone else's code that I've put in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key was to actually "define" classes, then they'll show up

```
class webserver:
    print('stuff')
```

However, now it's missing the relationships between the classes.
[pyreverse doesn't draw relationships/arrows/connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140119/pyreverse-doesnt-draw-relationships-arrows-connections)

Comment: What do you mean by "define"?

Comment: @pceccon this was 4 years ago, sorry but whatever I did in the snippet made things work. I never really went into python again but I figured out that what I did there back then was a bit wrong to begin with